# why is the output of $1 and $s or $/ will defferences

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

**I am begginer in ruby and untill reading the book of *the well-grounded rubyist* In section of Global variables I used the global variable ($1) but when i run it i get this error**

```
>> $2
=> nil
>> $2 = 2 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        2: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.3/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
SyntaxError ((irb):14: Can't set variable $2)
```

and i tried to create another variable with different name is workikng correctly

```
>> $s = "string"
>> puts $s
string
=> nil
```

also when I tried another variable ($/) and printed it i don't get the special value ***nil***

```
>> $/ = "h" 
>> p $/
"h"
=> "h"
```

why is all examples is defferent even if all of them are Global variables ?

Comment: Some global variables like `$2` are read-only – attempting to assign them raises a `SyntaxError`. Regarding the return values: `puts` returns `nil` and `p` returns its argument. That's how these methods work and it's unrelated to global variables.

Comment: Have a look at [Pre-defined global variables](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 0):

These are Pre-Defined global variables just as @stefan and @spickermann said.
In addition to that read this link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_predefined_variables.htm. It will be helpful.